# Best practice for list of countries (SQL, XML, ...)

Tags: mysql, sql, xml, database-design

While developing an website or web application, I'm wondering what is a best practice when you need list of world countries - is it better to use Countries table in SQL, store all values to XML or something else?

In example, let's say that I need to store country for each user (in SQL) and that I need to use list of countries in one (or more) dropdowns on my website.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to store country for each user (probably saving CountryId in users table suits best), you should have separate table for countries, and a `FOREIGN KEY` reference from user table to country table. You can also add/change country names using an admin panel, as and when country name changes.

But the interesting thing is that you need to query database each time page loads, to get all country names that are 'almost constant'!!.

A workaround for this situation is to get all country names first and cache them accordingly. When you populate country combo second time, get the list of countries from the cache.

- If cache is empty then get all countries from country table and cache them
- If cache item exists, then use cached countries (no database query)
- When you change country name from admin section, regenerate country cache also

> This approach best fit if you doesn't like to query database each and every time a page loads with 200+ records that are *almost constant and rarely updated*. Also this approach reduces database overhead.

Comment: On a side note, some DBMSes will cache query results and [MySQL appears to be one of them](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/query-cache.html), which is great for mostly-static data. It may not be as fast as a custom-made client-level cache, but can be used without changing existing clients.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you want your users to have countries *only* from that list, the DBMS would need to enforce the [FOREIGN KEY](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_foreignkey.asp) from users to the list, and this is possible only if the list is in the database table.

You'll also have much easier time filtering or JOININg<sup>1</sup> with the database table, should you ever need that.

Oh, and by the way, [countries do change](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geographical_renaming#Changes_resulting_from_splits_and_mergers), so you can't make this list completely constant, which is an additional argument for storing it in the database table.

---

*<sup>1</sup> For example, user table might be storing only the country code, in which case you'd have to JOIN it with countries table to get the full country name.*

Answer (score 0):

i think, there are many good ways to do this.
To fit your requirements, you should describe what exactly you need (Translations?)

If you store your countries in a SQL Database, there is a ready-to-import solution on geonames.org, the dumps can be downloaded here: http://download.geonames.org/export/dump/

In my opinion it is a good starting point.

Comment: I've also made my own solution for that (http://peric.github.com/GetCountries/) but I'm still wondering what is a best practice.
As I said before, I need to store country data for each user (in database), and I need to have a dropdown on my website where user can select country - and it's not important to have translations. I'm just what makes more sense and how are bigger web applications dealing with that?

Comment: what data is stored for each user? the country itself ist shared, isn't it? if you plan to scale very big, i suggest to take a look at nosql-databases (my favourites: mongodb and redis), it is easier to scale (but there are also drawbacks)